# How to get number of years between number of days since 1970/01/01 and a specified year

Tags: r

Create a variable that counts the number of years between the date of renovations and the sales date. If a house has not been renovated before, this variable should return the number of years since the house was built until the sales date.

date variable is the date the house was sold, stored as a numeric variable where the number is the number of days since 1 January 1970.

yr_built variable is an integer variable indicating the year that the house was built.

yr_renovated variable is an integer variable indicating the year that the house was renovated. (0 indicating no renovation)

I tried to execute a for loop where if there has been no renovations I divided the date variable by 365 and added 1970 then minus yr_built variable, else I divided the date variable by 365 and added 1970 then minus yr_renovated variable.

```
date <- c(16434, 16325, 16275, 16283, 16491, 16352, 16300, 16241, 16304, 16443)
yr_built <- c(1995, 2006, 2008, 1973, 1998, 1971, 2004, 1954, 1977, 1968)
yr_renovated <- c(0, 0, 0, 2000, 2010, 0, 0, 1992, 1995, 0)

data <- data.frame(date, yr_built, yr_renovated)
data

years_since_renovations <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(data$date)){

if(data$yr_renovated[i] == "0"){
years_since_renovations[i] = (floor(data$date[i]/365) + 1970) - (data$yr_built[i])
}

else{
years_since_renovations[i] = (floor(data$date[i]/365) + 1970) - (data$yr_renovated[i])
}

}

years_since_renovations
```

I would like to know if there is a more accurate way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start thinking more vectorized in R. You may do your calculations by sub-setting using `within`.

```
DATA <- within(DATA, {
  yr_renovated[yr_renovated == 0] <- floor(date[yr_renovated == 0]/365 + 1970)
  years_since_renovations <- yr_renovated - yr_built 
})
DATA
#     date yr_built yr_renovated years_since_renovations
# 1  16434     1995         2015                      20
# 2  16325     2006         2014                       8
# 3  16275     2008         2014                       6
# 4  16283     1973         2000                      27
# 5  16491     1998         2010                      12
# 6  16352     1971         2014                      43
# 7  16300     2004         2014                      10
# 8  16241     1954         1992                      38
# 9  16304     1977         1995                      18
# 10 16443     1968         2015                      47
```

(*Sidenote:* Always make sure that you do not overwrite any function name as you did with `data`.)

Alternatively in your example you could assign `"Date"`-`class` to your `"date"` column and strip off the years using `substr`. Note that the result differs a little from your formula above.

```
class(DATA$date) <- "Date"
DATA$years_since_renovations <- 
  with(DATA, ifelse(yr_renovated == "0",  as.numeric(substr(date, 1, 4)) - yr_built,
                    yr_renovated - yr_built))
DATA
#          date yr_built yr_renovated years_since_renovations
# 1  2014-12-30     1995            0                      19
# 2  2014-09-12     2006            0                       8
# 3  2014-07-24     2008            0                       6
# 4  2014-08-01     1973         2000                      27
# 5  2015-02-25     1998         2010                      12
# 6  2014-10-09     1971            0                      43
# 7  2014-08-18     2004            0                      10
# 8  2014-06-20     1954         1992                      38
# 9  2014-08-22     1977         1995                      18
# 10 2015-01-08     1968            0                      47
```

#### Data

```
DATA <- structure(list(date = c(16434, 16325, 16275, 16283, 16491, 16352, 
16300, 16241, 16304, 16443), yr_built = c(1995, 2006, 2008, 1973, 
1998, 1971, 2004, 1954, 1977, 1968), yr_renovated = c(2015, 2014, 
2014, 2000, 2010, 2014, 2014, 1992, 1995, 2015)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `date` to actual `Date`, get the year value from date and then use `ifelse` to calculate difference in year values.

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
data$year <- as.integer(format(data$date, "%Y"))
data$year_since_renovation <- with(data, ifelse(yr_renovated == 0, 
                               year - yr_built, year - yr_renovated))

data
#         date yr_built yr_renovated year year_since_renovation
#1  2014-12-30     1995            0 2014                    19
#2  2014-09-12     2006            0 2014                     8
#3  2014-07-24     2008            0 2014                     6
#4  2014-08-01     1973         2000 2014                    14
#5  2015-02-25     1998         2010 2015                     5
#6  2014-10-09     1971            0 2014                    43
#7  2014-08-18     2004            0 2014                    10
#8  2014-06-20     1954         1992 2014                    22
#9  2014-08-22     1977         1995 2014                    19
#10 2015-01-08     1968            0 2015                    47
```

If you don't need you can delete the `year` column later by doing `data$year <- NULL`.

Comment: Where is the effective difference to my solution?

Comment: @jay.sf  Sorry. I don't find any similarity with your solution here. Can you explain ?  Morever, if you check our both solutions give different answers.